# Pandas: counting unique datetime values in group by gives weird values

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, group-by

So I got this DataFrame, built in a way so that for column `id` equal to 2, we have two different values in column `num` and `my_date`:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 2], 
                  'my_date': [datetime(2017, 1, i) for i in range(1, 4)] + [datetime(2017, 1, 1)],
                  'num': [2, 3, 1, 4]
            })
```

For convenience, this is the DataFrame in a readable visual:

[image: dataframe]

If I want to count the number of unique values for each `id`, I'd do

```
grouped_a = a.groupby('id').agg({'my_date': pd.Series.nunique, 
                                 'num': pd.Series.nunique}).reset_index()
grouped_a.columns = ['id', 'num_unique_num', 'num_unique_my_date']
```

which gives this weird (?) result:

[image: grouped_dataframe]

Looks like the counting unique values on the `datetime` (which in Pandas converts to a `datetime64[ns]`) type is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is bug, see [github 14423](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14423).

But you can use [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) which works nice:

```
grouped_a = a.groupby('id').agg({'my_date': 'nunique', 
                                 'num': 'nunique'}).reset_index()
grouped_a.columns = ['id', 'num_unique_num', 'num_unique_my_date']
print (grouped_a)
   id  num_unique_num  num_unique_my_date
0   1               1                   1
1   2               2                   2
2   3               1                   1
```

If `DataFrame` have only `3` columns, you can use:

```
grouped_a = a.groupby('id').agg(['nunique']).reset_index()
grouped_a.columns = ['id', 'num_unique_num', 'num_unique_my_date']
print (grouped_a)
   id  num_unique_num  num_unique_my_date
0   1               1                   1
1   2               2                   2
2   3               1                   1
```

Comment: Fantastic! Also happen to know what's wrong with `Series.nunique`? I thought regular `'nunique'` was calling that.

Comment: jezrael beat me to the answer.  But this is weird!  Looks as though pandas is trying to impose the columns dtype when you pass a function.  But when you use the built in `nunique` it knows what to do.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know explain it well why it doesnt work nice with `pd.Series.nunique`, but try find it.

Comment: But is possible some bug.

Comment: One possible workaround would be to type cast `my_date` to string `dtype` to use the syntax as it is. Feel this issue persists with performing numerical aggregations on `datetime` columns.

Comment: I report it in [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15112).

Comment: Hello, would it be possible to update the answer since in python 3, the `nunique` method now passes a FutureWarning `In the future, NAT != NAT will be True rather than False.`? That would be great!

Comment: Hmmm, with OP sample data it works perfectly. I try add `NaN`s and it works perfect too `a = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 2], 
                  'my_date': [datetime(2017, 1, i) for i in range(1, 4)] + [datetime(2017, 1, 1)],
                  'num': [2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
            })` . Maybe some data problem?